# D3 Text not appearing my arc

Tags: d3.js

http://jsfiddle.net/xu77zz1m/

I have an example I pulled from online.  I can't figure out why no text appears when I try to append it to the path using this.

```
path.append('text')
  .attr('transform', function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr('dy', "0.35em")
  .attr('style', "color: white; font-size: 50px;")
  .text(function(d) {return "hellos"; });
```

It appears in the html as a  tag with my proper text that I am entering but nothing shows up on the page.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG Path (or SVG shapes such as rect and circle) can't have text appended to them.  You would need a parent 'g' element for each arc, which could include the path and text elements.

```
var arcs =svg.selectAll('.'+className)
                .data(pie(dataset))
                .enter()
                .append('g')

   var path = arcs.append('path')
            //etc

   arcs.append('text')
            //etc
```